# How can changing the plane affect the oscillation time period

Tags: homework-and-exercises, oscillators, home-experiment, moment-of-inertia

Consider a square frame, suspended by one of its corners (physical pendulum).

How will its time period vary if it oscillates:

- (a) perpendicular to the plane in which it is kept(plane of figure)
- (b) in the plane of figure

I understand that time period is $T=2\pi \sqrt{\dfrac{I}{mgd}}$ where $I$ is the moment of inertia and $d$ is the distance between the point of suspension and the frame's center of mass.

I believe the moment of inertia to not change in cases (a) and (b). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that saying "moment of inertia" is actually a short for "moment of inertia of object about some **axis**." Therefore, the moment of inertia does indeed depend on the axis of rotation.

I leave the computations up to you, but in some cases it may be that the moment of inertia will not change, so the period will not change.